# What is the best way to save a JWT Token in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, jwt, token

```
class ConstantService {
  static final FlutterSecureStorage _storage = FlutterSecureStorage();
  static FlutterSecureStorage get storage => _storage;

  static String token = '';

 

  Future<String?> readToken() async {
    try {
      String? token = await _storage.read(key: 'jwtToken');
      return token;
    } catch (e) {
      print('Error while reading token: $e');
      return null;
    }
  }
}
```

My issue is that in order for token to be initialised I must call readToken(). Is there a better way?

Comment: Make the `readToken` method static, then call it before you run your application; then it will be ready as soon as the user can interact with your application.